# How to combine variables in string in Perl

Tags: string, perl

```
$name = "LPA";
$date= 39;

$file = "/pathtoFile/window/$name/cavin_l/'$name'_formula_24rw$date.csv";
```

I want this to set `$file` equal to:

```
/pathtoFile/window/LPA/cavin_l/LPA_formula_24rw39.csv
```

But it is setting `$file` to:

```
/pathtoFile/window/LPA/cavin_l/'39.csv
```

Could someone help me figure out the correct syntax for what I am trying to accomplish? I cannot seem to get it.

Answer (score 5):

You fell victim to the archaic `'` (quote) package separator.

`$name'_formula_24` is interpreted as `$name::_formula24`, and since that variable is undefined, the empty string is interpolated.

You should change that to

```
$file = "/pathtoFile/window/$name/cavin_l/${name}_formula_24rw$date.csv"
```

Quoting from the man perldata:

> There are two package separators in Perl: A double colon ("::") and
>   a    single quote ("'").  Normal identifiers can start or end with a
>   double    colon, and can contain several parts delimited by double
>   colons.    Single quotes have similar rules, but with the exception
>   that they are    not legal at the end of an identifier: That is,
>   "$'foo" and "$foo'bar"    are legal, but "$foo'bar'" is not.

Answer (score 4):

The [double quotes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) `"..."` *interpolate* variables in the string. Then the problem is that in your attempt the variable names in the string are not cleanly delineated<sup>†</sup> and the interpreter ends up looking for

```
$name::_formula_24rw
```

That is, the variable `_formula_24rw` in the package `$name`; this is because a `'` after a variable name (so `'` after `$name` in your `$file`) is still [interpreted as a package separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) `::`, for historical reasons. As there is no such variable you end up with `'` and then the value for `$date`.

The most important takeaway: `use warnings;` **would have caught this**. Try to run

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $name = "LPA";
my $date= 39; 

my $file = "/pathtoFile/window/$name/cavin_l/'$name'_formula_24rw$date.csv";
```

and it prints

> Use of uninitialized value $name::_formula_24rw in concatenation (.) or string at ...

Please *always* have `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the beginning of a program.

---

So either use `${...}` where `{}` delimit the variable name

```
my $file = "/pathtoFile/window/$name/cavin_l/${name}_formula_24rw$date.csv";
```

or piece it together from separate strings

```
my $file = '/pathtoFile/window/' 
    . $name . '/cavin_l/' . $name . '_formula_24rw' . "$date.csv";
```

The `.` cannot be in a variable name so `$date` in that string is resolved correctly.<sup>†</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup> See [identifier parsing in perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Identifier-parsing) for details on how variable names are parsed in code.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use curly braces around the variable name like this:

```
$file = "/pathtoFile/window/$name/cavin_l/${name}_formula_24rw$date.csv";
```

This syntax is described in [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors)

> As in some shells, you can enclose the variable name in braces to
>   disambiguate it from following alphanumerics (and underscores).

Answer (score 0):

like most things in Perl there is many ways to do the same task.

You can use `{}` to define the boundaries of your variable name

`my $file1="/pathtoFile/window/$name/cavin_l/${name}_formula_24rw$date.csv";`

Alternatively you could use concatenation to join the string.

`my $file2="/pathtoFile/window/$name/cavin_l/" . $name ."_formula_24rw" . $date . ".csv";`

Both these methods produce the same result.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $name="LPA";
my $date="39";

my $file1="/pathtoFile/window/$name/cavin_l/${name}_formula_24rw$date.csv";
my $file2="/pathtoFile/window/$name/cavin_l/" . $name ."_formula_24rw" . $date . ".csv";

print "$file1\n$file2\n";
```

output

```
/pathtoFile/window/LPA/cavin_l/LPA_formula_24rw39.csv
/pathtoFile/window/LPA/cavin_l/LPA_formula_24rw39.csv
```